# Htaccess with multiple rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a problem with my rewrite rule in htaccess file. This is my code:

```
#BLOCK 1#
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ path_to_website/file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=pag-1&rew=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&country=0&pag=pag-1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /path_to_website/%2/? [R=301,L]

#BLOCK 2#
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ path_to_website/file.php?product=$1&country=$2&pag=pag-1&rew=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)&pag=pag-1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /path_to_website/%2/%4/? [R=301,L]

#BLOCK 3#
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ path_to_website/file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=pag-1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(?!=/)$ path_to_website/file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ path_to_website/file.php?product=$1&country=$2&pag=pag-1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ path_to_website/file.php?product=$1&country=$2&pag=$3 [L]
```

The first two block comes from submit form and the third block comes from an href.

I want to add the following rules without conflict with the other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ path_to_website/file2.php?product=$1&country=$2&product-details=$3 [L]
```

**edit**

Solved the proble, i just add another parameter to the rewrite for details-page:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+).([\w-]+)$ path_to_website/file2.php?product=$1&country=$2&product-details=$3&place-holder=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your htaccess file in your question, keep it up. Could you please do mention if there is any condition by which we will understand/segregate  that which URI should redirect to previous one OR which one to your newly mentioned url? Kindly explain more on it.

Comment: Ok. Here's the problem. If i click on this href:

path_to_website/file2.php?product=$1&country=$2&product-details=$3

I'm redirecting to 
path_to_website/file.php?product=$1$country=$2&pag=$3

Comment: I believe your new rule's condition part is already present in your htaccess file's one of the rules `^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$` so hence its the problem. So we need to mention a condition in rules to segregate between the 2. Else how coming request will come to know to which rule it should go for rewriting or redirecting.

Comment: So i need to write some RewriteCond? I'm sorry but i'm new in htaccess and it's very hard for me to understand it.

Comment: @Acr0no, yes that's correct. So there will be some logic no why you are redirecting one uris to one url and other to another, just mention that in your question and it will be easier for us to understand it more.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i edit my question. I don't know if I understand your request, sorry.

Comment: @Acr0no, sorry but its not clear. Its simple just let us know FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect in your already existing Rule AND FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect for you new rule, href which you are giving is an issue not information and its not clear, let us know more details on it, thank you.

Comment: Ok, so of I understand, from:

path_website/product/country/pag

To:
path_website/product/country/product_details

Comment: Why are you saying that you need to redirect _from_ `path_website/product/country/pag`, when in your question it says the link you clicked on pointed to `path_to_website/file2.php?product=$1&country=$2&product-details=$3`? The whole problem description is rather confusing.

Comment: Solved the problem, i will edit my question. Thanks to all :)

Comment: @Acr0no, Good that you have solved your problem, you should add your solution as an answer in this thread. Please don't update your question, rather add your solution as an answer, happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem, i just add another parameter to the rewrite for details-page:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+).([\w-]+)$ path_to_website/file2.php?product=$1&country=$2&product-details=$3&place-holder=$4 [L]
```

Thanks to all :)